# Search and Zoom in to a location

Tags: esri, arcgis-js-api

I am plotting some text graphics on a graphics layer and now I need to give an option on the map to search for a specific text and navigate to that location and zoom in.

Can someone please guide me with the approach?

Here is the sample code where if I search for 560001, the map should be zoom in to that location.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <style>
    html,
    body,
    #viewDiv {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.22/esri/themes/light/main.css">
  <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.22/"></script>
  <script>
    require([
      "esri/WebMap",
      "esri/views/MapView",
      "esri/Graphic",
      "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer",
      "esri/symbols/TextSymbol"
    ], function (WebMap, MapView, Graphic, GraphicsLayer, TextSymbol) {
      const webmap = new WebMap({
        portalItem: {
          id: "36f72c8a71b542399ca09e10c5aa55f4"
        }
      });
      const view = new MapView({
        container: "viewDiv",
        map: webmap,
        center: [-37.731338217717074, 175.22263172713014],
        zoom: 10
      });
      this.objectTypeList = [
        { Location: '560001', latitude: -37.731338217717074, longitude: 175.22263172713014 },
        { Location: '560002', latitude: -37.487705856583744, longitude: 175.09324140306873 },
        { Location: '560003', latitude: -37.505917118655056, longitude: 175.12036900524583 },
        { Location: '560005', latitude: -37.67287982024181, longitude: 175.23882277753953 },
        { Location: '560005', latitude: -37.67310492511848, longitude: 175.23890380457217 }
      ];
      var graphicsLayer = new GraphicsLayer();
      webmap.layers.add(graphicsLayer);
      this.objectTypeList.forEach(item => {
        var point = {
          type: "point",
          longitude: item.longitude,
          latitude: item.latitude
        };
        var textSymbol = new TextSymbol({
          color: "#BB0000",
          haloColor: "black",
          haloSize: "1px",
          text: `${item.Location}`,
          font: { size: 12, family: "Josefin Slab", weight: "bold" }
        });
        var pointGraphic = new Graphic({
          geometry: point,
          symbol: textSymbol
        });
        graphicsLayer.add(pointGraphic);
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="viewDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to find the selected (somehow) location in the graphics of `GraphicLayer` using the symbol text property.

Now, you are using geographic (lon, lat) to create the geometries but your map is in another spatial reference system. In that order to zoom to the geometries you will have to project them.

Take a look a the example I put for you, I use a simple select to choose the graphic, and I use a on client projection method, another option would be server side projection.

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <style>
        html,
        body,
        #viewDiv {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.22/esri/themes/light/main.css">
    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.22/"></script>
    <script>
        require([
            "esri/WebMap",
            "esri/views/MapView",
            "esri/Graphic",
            "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer",
            "esri/symbols/TextSymbol",
            "esri/geometry/SpatialReference",
            "esri/geometry/projection"
        ], function (WebMap, MapView, Graphic, GraphicsLayer, TextSymbol, SpatialReference, projection) {
            const webmap = new WebMap({
                portalItem: {
                    id: "36f72c8a71b542399ca09e10c5aa55f4"
                }
            });
            const view = new MapView({
                container: "viewDiv",
                map: webmap,
                center: [-37.731338217717074, 175.22263172713014],
                zoom: 10
            });
            this.objectTypeList = [
                { Location: '560001', latitude: -37.731338217717074, longitude: 175.22263172713014 },
                { Location: '560002', latitude: -37.487705856583744, longitude: 175.09324140306873 },
                { Location: '560003', latitude: -37.505917118655056, longitude: 175.12036900524583 },
                { Location: '560004', latitude: -37.67287982024181, longitude: 175.23882277753953 },
                { Location: '560005', latitude: -37.67310492511848, longitude: 175.23890380457217 }
            ];
            var graphicsLayer = new GraphicsLayer();
            webmap.layers.add(graphicsLayer);
            this.objectTypeList.forEach(item => {
                var point = {
                    type: "point",
                    longitude: item.longitude,
                    latitude: item.latitude
                };
                var textSymbol = new TextSymbol({
                    color: "#BB0000",
                    haloColor: "black",
                    haloSize: "1px",
                    text: `${item.Location}`,
                    font: { size: 12, family: "Josefin Slab", weight: "bold" }
                });
                var pointGraphic = new Graphic({
                    geometry: point,
                    symbol: textSymbol
                });
                graphicsLayer.add(pointGraphic);
            });

            projection.load().then(function() {
                const outSR = new SpatialReference({wkid: 2193});
                const dic = {};
                graphicsLayer.graphics.forEach(g => dic[g.symbol.text] = projection.project(g.geometry, outSR));
                view.when(function(){
                    const locationZoomButton = document.getElementById("locationZoomButton");
                    locationZoomButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
                        const locationSelect = document.getElementById("locationSelect");
                        const locationText = locationSelect.value;
                        if (dic.hasOwnProperty(locationText)) {
                            view.goTo(dic[locationText]);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <select id="locationSelect">
            <option value="560001">560001</option>
            <option value="560002">560002</option>
            <option value="560003">560003</option>
            <option value="560004">560004</option>
            <option value="560005">560005</option>
        </select>
        <button id="locationZoomButton"> Zoom </button>
    </div>
    <div id="viewDiv"></div>
</body>

</html>
```